# Radeon 9600 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Problem with driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, radeon, fglrx

I'm sorry for my bad English. I'm a Polish.

I have got with my Radeon 9600. I can not install drivers. I tried to install fglrx, but in the settings still wrote: (Graphics Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV350) instead of (ATI Radeon).
When I installed the "ati-driver-installer-9-3-x86.x86_64.run package". There was an error `[Error: ./default_policy.sh does not support version default:v2:i686:lib::none:3.13.0-39-generic; make sure that the version is being correctly set by --iscurrentdistro]`

And when I install fglrx and I type `"sudo aticonfig --initial"` pops `"aticonfig: No supported adapters detected."`

How do I install the unofficial ATI closed source drivers ?
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just open `Dash` type: `additional drivers` open the software and a list of drivers will show. Choose: `fglrx-updates` and click: `apply changes`. After the changes take place (look at the progress bar to see when done) restart the PC.

Comment: It did not help. Pops: "aticonfig: No supported adapters detected". After reboot, there is black screen and I must uninstall. :c Any advice?

Comment: Oh sorry for that, yeah don't worry about it just do a sudo amdcccle    --uninstall